# Replicate browser actions from command line

Tags: command-line, printing, chromium, pdf

I have an HTML file containing a slideshow, and I would like to print it in PDF. What I do so far is opening the file with Brave Browser and printing it in PDF from Brave (this only works with browsers with a Chromium base). I would like to automate this, so that I can print it with a single script.

I can open the file in Brave with:

```
brave-browser html_file.html
```

I am now wondering if I can print the page in PDF using Brave from the command line. Is this possible? More generally, can we replicate actions in browsers from the command line?

Comment: Did you check brave-browser documentation? Maybe it has a command line option like "-print" or something?

Comment: I couldn't even find a list of possible options [here](https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs.html), unless I didn't search at the right place. Sorry I don't know where to find this information

Comment: Well.. this documentation is very minimal :( I found something here by searching for "brave-browser command line options": https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044860011-How-Do-I-Use-Command-Line-Flags-in-Brave- . It refers to Windows version of Brave, but I think options are the same. Seems there is --print-to-pdf option...

Comment: It's strange because adding `--incognito` after the command in my post opens the HTML file in a private window (as expected) but `--print-to-pdf` does not work. Could you test it?

Comment: I can't because I don't have that browser. I just found some info that I shared with you.

Comment: If all else fails, I would try to download source code and search for the list of supported options. It must be there somewhere :)